# Does python use the count method to handle string and list the same way?

Tags: python

```
str1 = '123'
str2 = ''
print(str1.count('')) # print 4
print(str2.count('')) # print 1

list1 = ['123', '123']
list2 = ['', '']
print(list1.count('')) # print 0
print(list2.count('')) # print 2
```

Can all string be considered null-character conjugations?

Comment: in a string you can match the empty string on a lot of locations, for a list a full string compare is performed

Comment: Conjugations?  I'm not clear on your question, either in the title or the body.

Comment: In python the empty string `''` is considered a substring of all strings. That's [documented here](https://docs.python.org/3.8/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-operations).

Comment: The `count` method of the `str` type and the `count` method of the `list` type have *no connection whatsoever*.  Each was independently implemented, with different functionality as seemed appropriate for the different types.  Specifically, `list.count()` only finds individual elements of the list, but `str.count()` finds substrings of any length.